# Add incremented variable in jquery ajax success handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, auto-increment

I want to increment the value of a variable `ii`, but its value does not change. If I move `ii++;` before the `alert` function call, it increases but the value set to `#spanstatus` is always `0`.
How do I increment the value of `ii`, and still access it before my `$.ajax` call?

```
<html> 
      <span id="spanstatus"></span><br>

<script src="../js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var data = new FormData();
data.append('test', 'a');
data.append('test1', 'b');
data.append('test2', 'c');

function upload() {
        $('#spanstatus').html('');
        var ii=0;
        for(var [name, value] of data) {
            $('#spanstatus').append('<i>Uploading <b>"'+name+'"</b></i>...<span id="spanupload_'+ii+'">'+ii+'</span><br>');
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    method: 'POST',
                    timeout:2000,
                    url:'upload.php?val='+value,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:  value,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                    // async: false,
                    success:function(response){
                            $('#spanupload_'+ii).html(ii+' OK');
                            alert(ii+'ok='+name);
                            ii++;
                    }
                });
        }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    upload();
});

</script>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `success` handler does not execute until the the response is received, which happens sometime *later*, as this is an asynchronous handler. This means the value of `ii` will not have changed when you make each call to `$('#spanstatus').append`.

You could move the incrementing of `ii` so that it happens *before* the `$('#spanstatus').append`, but this introduces a new problem. In the `success` handler, `ii` will have been incremented once for each object in `data`, so it will always have the same value - in this case, `3` - when you call `$('#spanupload_'+ii).html(ii+' OK')`.

In order to keep a reference to *each iteration* within the for of loop, you must create a local, block-scoped variable with the value of `ii` at that iteration. You would need to do the same for `name`. The code would look like:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('test', 'a');
data.append('test1', 'b');
data.append('test2', 'c');

function upload() {
  $('#spanstatus').html('');
  var ii = 0;
  for (var [name, value] of data) {
    ii += 1;
    const nextii = ii;
    const nextName = name;

    $('#spanstatus').append('<i>Uploading <b>"' + nextName + '"</b></i>...<span id="spanupload_' + nextii + '">' + nextii + '</span><br>');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      method: 'POST',
      timeout: 2000,
      url: 'upload.php?val=' + value,
      dataType: "json",
      data: value,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      // async: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $('#spanupload_' + nextii).html(nextii + ' OK');
        alert(nextii + 'ok=' + nextName);
      }
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  upload();
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/9vL6fr1w/) for reference.

Comment: I have tested and yes it works. dont know why it works, is just change var to const?

Comment: `const` is part of it. `const` is block-scoped, which means we are creating a new variable on each iteration through the `for...of` loop which has a life only within its iteration. In contrast, `var`, is scoped to the function. This means there is a single variable used across each iteration of the `for...of` loop, so, by the time the `success` handler fires, the value of the variable declared with `var` will contain the last value assigned to it. Here is some more info on scopes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: You could also use `const` within the `for...of` loop so that you would not need to declare a new variable to hold the name value: `for (const [name, value] of data) {`. I have a forked version of the fiddle with this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/ok7vtu9y/

Comment: @Hida: Do the above comments help to clarify this for you?

Comment: yes. it so help me